# Including JS file in another JS file

Tags: javascript

I was wondering if there was a way to include a js file in another js file so that you can reference it. What I'm asking for is the JS equivalent of `include()` in PHP.

I've seen a lot of people recommend this method as an example:

```
document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="globals.js"></script>');
```

But I'm not sure if that's the same as `include()`

Comment: look for "javascript modules", there are a few common solutions (asm, browserify, require.js).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-to-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use document.write, it could wipeout the entire page if the page has already written. You can write something simple like this:

```
var jsToInclude = document.createElement('script');
jsToInclude.type = 'type/javascript';
jsToInclude.src = '/dir/somefile.js'; //  path to the js file you want to include
var insertionPointElement = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; // it could be the first javascript tag or whatever element 
insertionPointElement.parentNode.insertBefore(jsToInclude, insertionPointElement);
```

Answer (score 2):

Check out http://requirejs.org/ . You can define (AMD) modules and reference them in other modules like so

```
define(["path/to/module1", "path/to/module1")], function(Module1, Module2) {
    //you now have access
});
```